# liquid input type="radio" first child in loop

Tags: liquid

please tell me how I can output the first input type radio is checked? Here is the code:

```html
{% for variant in product.variants %}
    <div class="product-details__size">
        <input type="radio" value="{{ variant.id }}" name="variant_id" id="{{ variant.id }}" checked>
        <label for="{{ variant.id }}">{{ variant.title }}</label>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

if I do so, checked the last input

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're checking all your radios.

This test can be used to only check the first radio.

```
{% if forloop.index == 1 %}checked{% endif %}
```

Comment: Alternatively, [`{% if forloop.first %}`](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/objects/for-loops#first) results in cleaner code.